# How to group the value in from json response in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

How to summation the value curValue, PreVal using curMon value in below response 
e.g curMon `jan=23.4567+2045671+2045671`.

```
{
   "responseJSON":{
      "months":9,
      "rows":{
         "rowCount":93,
         "row":[
            {
               curMon:"Jan",
               curVal:23.4567,
               preVal: 33.5677

            },
            {
             curMon:"Feb",
               curVal:423.78482878,
               preVal: 460.57905554 
            },
            {
              curMon:"Jan"
               curVal:2045671,
               preVal:305678

            },
            {
             curMon:"Feb",
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20   
            },
            {
              curMon:"Jan",
               curVal:2045671,
               preVal:305678
            },
            {
               curMon:"Feb",
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20   
            },
            {
               curMon:"Mar",
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20   
            },
            {
               curMon:"Feb"
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20   
            },
            {
               curMon:"Jan"
               curVal:2045671,
               preVal:305678

            },
            {
               curMon:"Mar",
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20  
            },
            {
             curMon:"Feb"
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20     
            },
            {
              curMon:"Jan",
               curVal:2045671,
               preVal:305678 
            },
            {
             curMon:"Mar",
               curVal:26789.20,
               preVal: 24567.20  
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: each record of your response have to have an unambiguous idProperty.

Comment: I like how the response is JSON but it's labelled `responseXML`.

Comment: Do you know what summation means?